# How can i assign the name of an anchor tag to a variable in JS?

Tags: javascript, php, html, database

when the user clicks a link in the navbar I want to assign the name of the link (anchor tag) to a JS variable. Furthermore I then want use that variable to call data from SQL via php.

For example if the user clicks "FC Bayern München" in the navbar I want the application to display the according data which i have stored in SQL (..building a soccer dashboard to learn programming..)

I didn't come pretty far with it as of now:

```
$('ul.subbar li a').on('click', function(e) { // User clicks nav link
  e.preventDefault(); // Stop loading new link
  var team =
```

html structure:

```
    <div id="sidebar">
      <header>
        <a href="#">DASOCC</a>
      </header>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="countries"><img src="images/germany.png" alt="germany">1. Bundesliga
          <ul class="subbar">
            <li><a class="team">FC Bayern München</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">Borussia Dortmund</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">Bayer Leverkusen</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">RB Leipzig</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">VfL Wolfsburg</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">SC Freiburg</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">Eintracht Frankfurt</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">Borussia M. Gladbach</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">FC Schalke 04</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">TSG Hoffenheim</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">1. FC Union Berlin</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">Fortuna Düsseldorf</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">Werder Bremen</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">1. FC Köln</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">SC Paderborn</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">FC Augsburg</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">Hertha BSC Berlin</a></li>
          </ul>
```

php code to grab data from SQL (I will have to change this to select X,Y,Z where name = assigned variable (at least this is how my current plan looks like ;p)

```
<?php
  include_once 'dbh.inc.php';


  $sql = "SELECT name from teams;";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      /*echo $row['name'];*/
    }
  }
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to load the data via _ajax_? What exactly is your question?

Comment: my first question is how to assign the click club name to a variable so i can use that variable to call the required data from SQL. The second question is how to create the smartest solution for loading data into a dashboard on user selection within the navbar. Ajax is probably the best solution, indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want to get the HTML of every anchor on each click. Solution is-

```
$('ul.subbar li a').on('click', function(e) { 
 e.preventDefault(); 
 var team = $(this).html();
})
```

You will get the name of each anchor tag.

Comment: hm i don't get a console.log output for console.log(team) when i click a team on the navbar

Comment: update: it worked. the link to the js file was in the top of my index.php file. I put it to the bottom and now it works. But why is that? I mean let the js file load, then the html, then i click on the navbar, why does this approach won't work? Just for the records, thank you.

Comment: Note: If you are using jQuery then put the jquery.min.js in the head part and all your custom js file or functions in footer.